# Таблицы бд под пример

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть вещи, (Меч, Щит, Перчатка), например один меч может давать блок, а другой нет, а щит вообще не наносит урон. Как из соображений быстродействия разбить эти данные в таблице:
**Вот так:**

> Таблица вещей-> id | name | damage | armor | block |.... |.....

**Или так**

> Таблица вещей-> id | name
>
> Таблица характеристик-> id | id_вещи | action | value

Посоветуйте пожалуйста

Comment: второй вариант полезен, если характеристики постоянно добавляются. если список характеристик фиксированный, то одна таблица удобнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id`,`class`,`subclass`,`unk0`,`name`,`displayid`,`Quality`,`Flags`,`FlagsExtra`,`BuyCount`,`BuyPrice`,`SellPrice`,`InventoryType`,`AllowableClass`,`AllowableRace`,`ItemLevel`,`RequiredLevel`,`RequiredSkill`,`RequiredSkillRank`,`requiredspell`,`requiredhonorrank`,`RequiredCityRank`,`RequiredReputationFaction`,`RequiredReputationRank`,`maxcount`,`stackable`,`ContainerSlots`,`StatsCount`,`stat_type1`,`stat_value1`,`stat_type2`,`stat_value2`,`stat_type3`,`stat_value3`,`stat_type4`,`stat_value4`,`stat_type5`,`stat_value5`,`stat_type6`,`stat_value6`,`stat_type7`,`stat_value7`,`stat_type8`,`stat_value8`,`stat_type9`,`stat_value9`,`stat_type10`,`stat_value10`,`ScalingStatDistribution`,`ScalingStatValue`,`dmg_min1`,`dmg_max1`,`dmg_type1`,`dmg_min2`,`dmg_max2`,`dmg_type2`,`armor`,`holy_res`,`fire_res`,`nature_res`,`frost_res`,`shadow_res`,`arcane_res`,`delay`,`ammo_type`,`RangedModRange`,`spellid_1`,`spelltrigger_1`,`spellcharges_1`,`spellppmRate_1`,`spellcooldown_1`,`spellcategory_1`,`spellcategorycooldown_1`,`spellid_2`,`spelltrigger_2`,`spellcharges_2`,`spellppmRate_2`,`spellcooldown_2`,`spellcategory_2`,`spellcategorycooldown_2`,`spellid_3`,`spelltrigger_3`,`spellcharges_3`,`spellppmRate_3`,`spellcooldown_3`,`spellcategory_3`,`spellcategorycooldown_3`,`spellid_4`,`spelltrigger_4`,`spellcharges_4`,`spellppmRate_4`,`spellcooldown_4`,`spellcategory_4`,`spellcategorycooldown_4`,`spellid_5`,`spelltrigger_5`,`spellcharges_5`,`spellppmRate_5`,`spellcooldown_5`,`spellcategory_5`,`spellcategorycooldown_5`,`bonding`,`description`,`PageText`,`LanguageID`,`PageMaterial`,`startquest`,`lockid`,`Material`,`sheath`,`RandomProperty`,`RandomSuffix`,`block`,`itemset`,`MaxDurability`,`area`,`Map`,`BagFamily`,`TotemCategory`,`socketColor_1`,`socketContent_1`,`socketColor_2`,`socketContent_2`,`socketColor_3`,`socketContent_3`,`socketBonus`,`GemProperties`,`RequiredDisenchantSkill`,`ArmorDamageModifier`,`Duration`,`ItemLimitCategory`,`HolidayId`,`ScriptName`,`DisenchantID`,`FoodType`,`minMoneyLoot`,`maxMoneyLoot`,`WDBVerified`

Для примера. Данные хранящиеся в таблице игровых серверов WoW. Используйте первый вариант, не извращайтесь над данными.